# Prevent function generating private addresses

Tags: python

How do i prevent this python from generating private addresses?

```
def gen_ip():
    b1 = random.randrange(0, 255, 1)
    b2 = random.randrange(0, 255, 1)
    b3 = random.randrange(0, 255, 1)
    b4 = random.randrange(0, 255, 1)
    ip = str(b1)+"."+str(b2)+"."+str(b2)+"."+str(b4)
    ip = ip[::-1]
    return ip
```

Comment: Don't invoke it.

Comment: This might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces

Comment: Side notes: You probably don't want to include `b2` twice and leave `b3` out. And you probably don't want to generate valid addresses and then reverse them into usually-invalid addresses. Also, `randrange(0, 255, 1)` can't return `255`; if that's not what you want, either use `256` or use `randint`. (And you can just write `randrange(255)` if you want the default start of 0 and step of 1.)

Comment: Do you really want to avoid private IPs, or do you *only* want to include *public* ips? (IOW, do you also want to exclude 127/8 and 100.64/10?)

Answer (score 1):

```
def isPrivateIp (ip):
    # fill this
    return True or False

ip = gen_ip()
while isPrivateIp(ip):
    ip = gen_ip()
```

Comment: What would be the most inexpensive way to exclude 17891328 addresses

Comment: Well, there are 4294967296 total addresses. Those 17891328 are just 0.4% of the available addresses. So just regenerating a new IP if you get a private one will be very efficient. You can improve quite a lot though, if you move the private IP check into the generator. For example the whole `10.0.0.0/8` range is private, so if you generate `b1` (btw. I wouldn’t reverse the generated IP, to make it easier), and get a `10`, you could just run that again, without having to run `b2-b4`.

Comment: Excluding `10.` that way is easy, but excluding the other two blocks without breaking the uniform distribution is less so. (You have to make `192` and `176` appropriately less likely than the other numbers if you don't want `192.1.2.3` to come up more often than `191.1.2.3`.) Doing what this answer does is by far simpler, and probably more efficient as well.

Comment: You _can_ get a decent speedup—and simpler code to boot—by doing the `isPrivateIp` check on the four bits while they're still integers, and only converting to string once you've got one that passed. But really, is reducing a 10.1us operation to 9.4us (from a quick `timeit` test) really going to make a difference in your code? If not, why worry about "most inexpensive" at all?

Answer (score 0):

I think poke's answer is great. But if you're going to be generating and consuming these in a loop, I'd just create an infinite iterator and filter it:

```
# Same as your function, but without the bugs
def gen_ip():
    return '.'.join(str(random.randrange(256)) for _ in range(4))

# Obviously not the real logic; that's left as an exercise to the reader of
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces
def is_private_ip(ip):
    return not ip.startswith('2')

# Now this is an infinite iterator of non-private IP addresses.
ips = ifilterfalse(repeatfunc(gen_ip), is_private_ip)
```

Now you can get 10 IPs like this:

```
>>> take(10, ips)
['205.150.11.90',
 '203.233.175.192',
 '211.241.64.223',
 '250.224.20.172',
 '203.26.103.176',
 '20.107.5.214',
 '204.181.205.180',
 '234.24.178.180',
 '22.225.212.59',
 '237.122.140.163']
```

I've used `take` and `repeatfunc` from the [recipes in the `itertools` docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes), and `ifilterfalse` from `itertools` itself.

Answer (score -1):

More efficient solution is to create a list of all possible addresses (or parts of address), generate index in this array and select element by this index. Something like this:

```
bs = [0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 191, 193, ..., 255]
idx = random.randrange(0, len(ips), 1) 
b = bs[idx]
# or simpler: b = random.choice(bs)
```

Comment: First, this is wrong—it will skip, e.g., 192.20.30.40 even though only 192.168/16 is private. It also skips all `0` components. Finally, I'm not sure whether you mean "efficient" in the usual "minimal CPU time" sense, or in some other sense, but I doubt this is true. For example, `random.choice(bs)` will always be faster than `bs[random.randrange(len(bs))]`.

Comment: @abarnert: to filter all real private ips the entire function is to be rewritten with regard to Wikipedia article you pointed to. So I just showed the way of efficient generation of a number from non continuous range. It is efficient in algorithmic sense: with a filter/loop you never know how many iterations you will need. Imagine that `randrange` generates 192, then 10, then 172, then 192 again... Picking up value from finite set (no matter with `randrange` and index or `choice`) will always give you next allowed number from the very first time. The only claim I agree with is about 0 in IP.

Comment: First, how are you going to adjust this solution to actually be correct? However you do it, it will no longer be just picking values out of a list, so any of your claims for efficiency about this incorrect answer are irrelevant. Second, the expected amortized cost of filtering out about 1% of all possible values is about 1%; the expected amortized cost of doing twice as much work as necessary to pick a number out of a range is about 100%. Unless you're doing hard real-time, you're focusing on the wrong place (as always true when someone posts an answer that starts "most efficient").

Comment: @abarnert: please, do not say that the answer is incorrect if you don't understand it. And, please, do not reason about CPU efficiency without knowing the entire stack. Picking up random number from array doesn't introduce 100% overhead - random number is generated exactly once. At the same time `if`s (loops/filters) introduce real challenge for CPU. You also haven't provided implementation of `is_private_ip()`, which may include multiple conditions. You don't know Python implementation, subclass of Random and operating system in use. So the only enhancement you can introduce is algorithmic.

Comment: About full implementation: depending on requirements, there may be 2 possible ways. If author needs just some puplic ips, not necessarily from entire possible range (and this is my assumption about the question), direct solution will work pretty well. Otherwise it is possible to generate and save all allowed ips and pick one from them (see line about address *or* part of address in my question). I don't claim that this solution is elegant or the only correct or suitable for all cases, I only claim that this will generate new ip from the very first call, without need to recompute value on fail.

Comment: I do understand your code. I don't think you do. How are you going to skip `192.168.1.2` but not `192.167.1.2` with this design? If you're planning to have special `b2` blocks for 172 and 192, you're adding a lot of complexity which will take more time than it saves—and you also won't get a uniform distribution anymore. And it's not true that you "only claim this will generate new ip from the very first call", you explicitly claim that it's a "more efficient solution". Which is not true.

Comment: For evidence that it's not more efficient, see http://pastebin.com/Qj5zESkW, where I implemented the fastest version of your algorithm I could come up with (which isn't actually correct), and timed it against the fastest version of poke's algorithm (which is). In CPython 2.7, his ran in 86% the time of yours; in 3.3, 98%; in PyPy, 101%. Meanwhile, the cost of implementing `choice` yourself instead of using the right function doubles the time. So, you've put your effort into the wrong place—aiming at a 1-14% improvement instead of a 50% improvement—and you didn't even succeed at that effort.

Comment: @abarnert: you are too busy proving incorrectness of my solution and nitpicking on words to actually grasp main idea. You missed the point about algorithmic efficiency and, in general, the goal of my answer. Your implementation is quite far from what I described, and I'm not going to explain it one more time. If you only want to be right and not to find best solution, I won't be able to explain anything to you. In my opinion, I have already answered all your (quite aggressive) comments, so I don't see the point in further talking.

Comment: From my very first reply: "The expected amortized cost of filtering out about 1% of all possible values is about 1%". That addresses the algorithmic complexity. The average case is O(1.01N) == O(N). You never replied to that or addressed it in any way; you just ignored it and went on to a different argument, and eventually forgot about it and started making the same argument again.